# Difference between callbackUrl and function in passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to find out how Facebook authentication works when using passport-facebook with node/express.

I'm confused about the callbackURL and the function that follows below.

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between setting a callbackURL (is this where a successful login attempt end up? and the function(accessToken, ...) which also seems to be invoked after logging in.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`callbackURL` is a URL that facebook's web servers themselves will use at the end of the process. Facebook's servers will send a 301 redirect response causing the user's browser to navigate to this URL. So this is essentially a configuration option you are sending to facebook itself, and passport.js is handling the specifics of when and where to send it. When the whole oauth dance is done, the callback function is a way for passport to give control back to your code and say "hey, look it worked. Here's the goodies on the logged-in user", so you can do your `findOrCreate`. The details inside that function typically vary per-application whereas the oauth dance is always the same. So that's why passport uses a function callback there. It allows you a hook for application-specific or custom logic.

Comment: But how does the callbackURL get mapped to the Passport module?

Comment: Passport adds routes to express both for the URL that the browser uses to start authentication as well as the URL of the final facebook callback that the browser will request after successful authentication. Both of these are explicitly configured by `app.get` calls which must match exactly with the `app.use` call in order for everything to work properly. See the passport guide's facebook example for the details.

Comment: The guide shows code for explicitly adding two routes to the app. So it looks like there are two sets of routes. The manually added ones and the ones automatically added by Passport.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Passport provides the route handler functions (the implementation) but the app developer must explicitly code the express routes that map the URLs to the passport functions as well as installing the passport middleware. Passport doesn't automatically add any routes or middleware. It just provides the implementation functions. Clear now?

Comment: Not really. In the guide the second route for the call back is mapped to the *same* function call as the one that does the redirect. That doesn't make sense - its doing something different. And then the parameter for the call back is an object with another two routes - one for success and one for failure?? So I'm just guessing... does calling that same method again result in the call to the function declared when configuring the strategy?

Comment: And also, how would I call the authenticate method from a separate module so that I don't have to configure authentication strategies in app.js? So another custom route would forward to the Passport authentication method.

Comment: I think you should post a new question instead of extending this comment thread. All this stuff (routes, URLs, callbacks, middleware, strategies, options, redirects. etc) is pretty confusing. Oauth2 is pretty complex. I'm not sure I'll be able to help you adequately.